# Creating deep-nested objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, properties, nested

When loading JSON from a server, I need to create objects. The objects do not always exist beforehand.Therefore I have to check that each level exists before adding a new level. Is there a better way to do this, then the following way:

```
var talkerId = commentDB.val().to;
var commentId = commentDB.val().id

if (!store.talkers.hasOwnProperty(talkerId)) {
    store.talkers[talkerId] = {}
}
if (!store.talkers[talkerId].hasOwnProperty(comments)) {
    store.talkers[talkerId] = { comments: {} };
}
if (!store.talkers[talkerId].comments.hasOwnProperty(commentId)) {
    store.talkers[talkerId].comments[commentId] = {}
}
store.talkers[talkerId].comments[commentId].author = commentDB.val().author;
```

Comment: See [`lodash.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#set).

Comment: Could you not simply return JSON from the server and then use `JSON.parse()` to convert to an object?

Comment: I can't return from the server, because I join two fields of data, and create combined JSON in the client.

Comment: So you make 2 calls to the server, each of them making a DB call, then you return 2 datasets to the client and that merges them into one object?

Comment: @31piy, it did the job :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cour reduce the keys by using the object an check if the key exist. if not create a new property with an empty object.

```
var dbValue = commentDB.val();

[dbValue.to, 'comments', dbValue.id].reduce(
    (o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {},
    store.talkers
).author = commentDB.val().author;
```

Comment: Thanks, very cool, but reduce has logic that I find hard to follow when maintaing a code

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a function

```
function checkAndCreateProperty(arr, baseVar) {
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if (!baseVar.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
           baseVar[arr[i]] = {};
      }
      baseVar = baseVar[arr[i]];
   }
}


checkAndCreateProperty(["talkerId", "comments", commentDB.val().id, commentDB.val().author], store.talkers)
```

Answer (score 1):

After the suggestion of @31piy I went for the most simple solution:

using lodash _.set

```
var talkerId = commentDB.val().to;
var commentId = commentDB.val().id;

_.set(store.talkers, '[' + talkerId + '].comments[' + commentId + '].author', commentDB.val().author)
```